# How do I use Getopt::Long to parse arguments that may have spaces?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I have a shell script that spits out a line as follows:

```
prog_name -options ...
```

To be specific, as an example:

`prog_name -filter_arg +define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long -disp_arg +define size=40 res=30`

Please note that there are no quotes above and I do not have control to modify the shell script. [However, I am not sure if I can insert quotes to the above syntax through some other program.].

Now, I want to send the above to a Perl program to parse the options so that it associates
`+define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long` to the option `-filter_arg`  and
`+define size=40 res=30` to the option `-disp_arg`.

Can someone please help me do this?

Answer (score 5):

`Getopt::Long` is simply parsing the `@ARGV` list as provided to the Perl program. If the parameters are separate entries in the `@ARGV` list, `Getopt::Long` will parse them that way. Your problem is that the shell is putting each argument as a separate parameter since there are no quotes around them.

Your choice is to either munge the parameters before your Perl script runs, or by munging `@ARGV` itself to combine the parameters into the values they're suppose to be in.

For the first option, you can use `sed` to take the output of your program and add in the missing quotes. If you're program always spits out fields like this:

```
prog_name -filter_arg +define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long -disp_arg +define size=40 res=30
```

You could pipe that through `sed` like this:

```
$ orig_prog | sed -e 's/filter_arg /filter_arg "/' -e 's/ -disp_arg /" -disp_arg "/' -e 's/$/"/'
```

Or this:

```
$ orig_prog | sed -e 's/^\(.*\) -filter_arg \(.*\) -disp_arg \(.*\)$/\1 -filter_arg "\2" -disp_arg "\3"/'
```

That will put the quotes around your parameters and it'll look like this:

```
prog_name -filter_arg "+define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long" -disp_arg "+define size=40 res=30"
```

That way, `@ARGV` will be setup correctly so the `GetOptions` function will work the way you want it to.

The other way is to munge `@ARGV` once you're Perl program runs before you call `GetOptions`:

```
my $value;
my @newArgv;
foreach my $param (@ARGV) {
   if ($param =~ /^-/) {
   if ($value) {
    push (@newArgv, $value);
    $value = "";
   }
   push(@newArgv, $param);
   } else {
   $value = $value ? "$value $param" : "$param";
   }
}
push (@newArgv, $value) if ($value);
@ARGV = @newArgv;
```

In the above example, `@ARGV` will have the following values:

```
@ARGV[0] = -filter_arg
@ARGV[1] = +define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long
@ARGV[2] = -disp_arg
@ARGV[3] = +define size=40 res=30
```

And, `Getopts::Long` should now work the way you want it to. ***A little side note***: In newer versions of `Getopt::Long`, you're able to use other arrays besides `@ARGV`. You simply put the array you want to use as the first argument in `GetOptions`:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromArray);

GetOptionsFromArray (
    \@newArgs,
    "filter_arg=s" => \$filter_arg,
    "disp_arg=s"   => \$disp_arg,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $options = {};
@ARGV=qw<-filter_arg +define BOOST +noconvtest +actuate-long -disp_arg +define size=40 res=30>;
GetOptions( 
    $options # store in hash ref
    , qw<filter_arg define=s noconvtest actuate-long> 
    , disp_arg => sub { 
        # this will contain "+define size=40 res=30"
        $options->{disp_arg} = join( ' ', delete @ARGV[0..$#ARGV] );
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think you can use GetOpt::Long to do this, at least not directly.

You'd need I think to do a first pass yourself, something like

```
my @filters;
my $filter = [];

foreach (@ARGV) {
  if ($_ eq '+filter') {
    push @filters, $filter;
    $filter = [];
  } else {
    push @$filter, $_;
  }
}
push @filters, $filter if @$filter;

foreach (@filters) {
  Getopt::Long::GetOptionsFromArray(@$_, ...

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Axeman, David and Colin. Really appreciate your prompt response. And in the true spirit of Perl, you have shown how the problem can be solved in multiple ways! I learnt a lot following each of your postings carefully.  Warm Regards.

Comment: Misses the point that the options were split by the shell, not by Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Getopt::Long can parse your command line as is:

```
my (@filter_arg, @display_arg);
GetOptions('filter_arg=f{1,5}' => \@filter_arg, 'display_arg=i{1,5}' => \@display_arg);
```

You'll get arrays of parms.

Please see [Getopt::Long - Options with multiple values](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong#Options-with-multiple-values) for a more verbose explanation of the multivalued parameter handling that's already available.